# Move and Change Pagefile.sys size on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, pagefile

Does anyone know how to move the page file on Windows Server 2008.  Everything seems to be in a different spot on this OS!

Also, I would like to tweak it's size.  If you know where that is (probably in the same spot) please let me know.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Advanced System Settings, on the Advanced tab click the Performance/Settings button.

Advanced System Settings can be reached by right clicking My Computer and choosing Properties or from Server Manager by clicking the Change System properties link.

JR

Comment: you can also launch "sysdm.cpl" from the run box to get there as well. Yet another method is to launch "SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe" which is what the Server Manager launches.

Answer (score 2):

Using the WMIC command line tool.. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424384(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_Step1